# How does summon item work in 1.12?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making with my friends a kind of bed wars server and for the generators I need to use `/summon item`. i tried to use `/summon item` and in chat appeared `unable to summon item`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to [summon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon) an item, you have to add a [data tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Data_tags) to specify which item to summon and the quantity of that item.

Here is the command:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"<item>",Count:1b}}
```

Replace `<item>` with the item to summon. Must be a valid [item id](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values/Item_IDs), or [block id](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Block_IDs) for which items exist.

Here is an example command which summons a diamond sword:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",Count:1b}}
```

You could also use a [minecraft item generator](https://minecraftcommand.science/custom-item-generator) which supports summoning items.

Comment: /summon item (<--- lowercase "i")

Comment: You are summoning an entity ID.  The correct entity ID in 1.12 was capitol I in _Item_.  Visit the [Minecraft Wiki on Item(entity) data values](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Item_(entity)#Data_values) to learn more.